# How do you connect to BusinessObjects?

Tags: database, odbc

I have the rights to log into a BOXI server and build queries and reports, but can only export 100,000 rows at a time.

I have tools on my desktop that can connect to databases via things like ODBC.

Is there a way to use ODBC or some other connection type to connect to BusinessObjects?

---Edit---
In response to the first two answers:

Thank you for your insight.

In a perfect world, I would be glad to connect directly to the database servers that BOXI is pulling data from, but I can not. The only access I have to the data is through BOXI.

I understand the row limitation is set by the BOXI admins, but they will not adjust it.

---Edit 2---
Answers to two more questions:

1. "And you should think of it, what will you do with a query with more than 100k row ?"

I would like to analyze the data with tools on my desktop that are designed to connect directly to data sources.

2. "Is there any valuable information in a 100k row answer ?"

I am not look for 100k rows to be my final answer, I am hoping to analyze millions of rows.

A better way to describe my issue:

I have access to data in BOXI, but it is limited in the amount of analysis I can preform, so I want to connect to the data in BOXI and analyze it with tools on my desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at the question a different way: what you want to do is capture the query that BusinessObjects is executing on the database server, and then run that same query yourself on the database server.

For example, if it's accessing data stored in Microsoft SQL Server, you can ask the database administrator to run Profiler to capture your queries while you're executing the report in BO.  He can then give you the queries you ran, and you can execute those same queries in your own tools to get the results directly.

Update: I saw your edits, and what you're asking for just isn't possible.  BOXI isn't a middleware tier for accessing millions of rows of data via ODBC.  You either need to get the admins to allow you to export more data, or you need to connect to the underlying database.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right the limitation of how many rows are allowed to be exported is a configuration value. Look up in the connection properties what the limitations are and set them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This 100k row is a limitation set by admin of BO XI.

And you should think of it, what will you do with a query with more than 100k row ?

Is there any valuable information in a 100k row answer ?

BOXI will give you report, graph, filtering, and plenty of option, to do the same query directly on the DB will :

- give you a huge blurb of more than 100 (could be 1M rows)
- problems with the DBA who will not like you run your query at peak time.

You should think of your query and reduce the amount of data if you want that real time, or schedule the report, to have the full answer during off-peak.